# Is my Windows 7 x86 license key valid for a x64 installation of Windows?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

I've just got a new laptop with Windows 7 x86 Home Premium installed, however I ideally I'd like to be running a 64-bit operating system:

- Is my Windows license key "generic" (in that it entitles me to install either a x86 or x64 edition of Windows), or does this licence key specific to the x86 version of Windows?
- Is there any way of me installing and running Windows 7 Home Premium x64 using my x86 license key?

Comment: Is there anything else I can provide to get this marked as answered?

Comment: @James - Sorry, I haven't had a chance to actually try 
this out yet and I don't like to accept answers until I've proven that they do the trick - don't worry, I will mark it as answered eventually! :-)

Comment: Did this work eventually? I see the answer is not still accepted, therefore I am still unsure if one can rely upon this.

Comment: OP just can't be bothered to mark this answered. It does work fine, I do it constantly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes your Windows 7 key works for both x32 and x64 versions of Home Premium.

Source: Microsoft eOpen only provides 1 key per purchase, regardless of how many computers you have or which architecture (x32/x64) you are using. Furthermore, Microsoft TechNet subscribers get 10 keys for each flavor of Windows 7 (Home Premium, Professional, Ultimate, etc.) These keys can be used to install on either architecture.

Comment: Just as an additional note.... It only works within the same class... A "Retail Home Premium" key will only work on "Retail Home Premium", not on "OEM Home Premium", "Retail Ultimate", etc...

Comment: @JamesWatt: There is one cruel exception. OEM version are sold seperatly for 32 OR 64 bit and officially not allowed to be changed btw. 32/64 bit.