# Can I upgrade an OEM Windows 7 x86 to x64?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is my Windows 7 x86 license key valid for a x64 installation of Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/136899/is-my-windows-7-x86-license-key-valid-for-a-x64-installation-of-windows)

I was thinking of purchasing an Acer laptop with 4GB of RAM that has Windows 7 Professional preinstalled with downgrade rights to Windows XP Professional (which I will not be using). As far as I can reason, because of the downgrade rights, it includes the 32-bit version (x86) of Windows 7. I would like to use the 64-bit (x64) version of Windows 7 in order to access all 4GB of RAM (instead of the ~3.5GB cap 32-bit has). Is it possible to somehow switch my OEM copy of Windows 7 from 32- to 64-bit and if so, can someone help point me in the right direction to accomplishing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32-bit serial numbers are valid for 64-bit installs.  The only issue, then, is getting a hold of an OEM distribution of the installation media.  Remember that retail copies do not work, as they're pidded differently.

You can either call your manufacturer and ask them for a 64-bit install media, or recovery disk that has a 64-bit version of Windows, or you can try and call Microsoft and have them send you one.  It's possible they will, for a fee.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda what I figured. I will try to contact them and see. I don't mind paying a fee that much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your key is valid for x64 - dunno how to get the installation media.

Source:
[Is my Windows 7 x86 license key valid for a x64 installation of Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/136899/is-my-windows-7-x86-license-key-valid-for-a-x64-installation-of-windows)